# Large files split when uploaded to cloud (B2 Backblaze)

Tags: backup, dropbox, google-drive, amazon-s3, icloud

I'm uploading some ISO files which I made from DVDs to B2 Backblaze cloud. But I see they split there:

[image]

There are also some 0 bytes size files, which seems strange.

How can this be explained?

I'm curious if the same happens in other cloud storage services.

Comment: What happens if you mouse-over one of those little ⓘ hint/info icons over on the right, ir maybe click on one?

Comment: Quite not sure, but maybe there are some changes were made while the file was uploading.